# Honeymoon package times?

Tags: cruising

I heard cruise ships like Royal Caribbean will leave gifts for "honeymoon planned" couples. My question is, do these cruise lines typically give these gifts in the packages (like wine/champagne) upon arrival or no?

I ask because I want to know exactly how this will turn out 100%.

I called them and they had no perfect answer. When you reserve a "honeymoon" preferred vacation, the cruise lines will typically have a setup for the couple -- like, as mentioned, champagne and/or wine; drinking glasses; bouquets/flowers; chocolates; other gifts; etc.

My question is, at approximately how many minutes or hours after embarking is this likely to be found or where? Like, when me and my husband get on the ship, will I find this stuff setup; or will I see it after time has progressed? It should be champagne and/or wine and chocolates, flowers, etc.; I need to know about how many minutes or hours after embarking I should see this, and approximately how long after stepping in the ship before it takes off relative to when I should find these gifts.

I know this question is a massive stretch, but try and bear with me! 
Thanks!

Comment: This does seem like a stretch. A typical honeymoon cruise is not (well, no longer) a surprise to anyone involved, so it doesn't seem like the cruise line would plan such extras down to the minute. If you've asked them directly and they have no definite answer, it would be hard for us to give a *better* answer, as there are too many possible factors involved.

Comment: I doubt there's any true guarantee. The cruise line may or may not plan for it to be in the cabin waiting for you, but there's thousands of people getting on the ship at once and embarkation is a very busy time. Each individual ship may do its own thing, and it may come down to when the individual crewmember assigned to the task has a free moment. The order could even get lost and you might have to call and ask for it. At best, they're promising that the couple gets their gift by the end of the cruise or you'll get a refund.

Comment: @ZachLipton - a cruise line that incompetent would not be in business that long.  The cabin stewards have a list of their guests, with all requests noted before the ship sails.

Comment: Why do you need to know the exact time after boarding that you will receive your gifts? I can't fathom a reason why that would be necessary. To answer one of your questions, they'll probably put it in your cabin.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai I have assumed the exact minute was required so as not to be engaged in honeymooner's conjugal bliss when the steward arrived with the stuff. It could spoil the rapture to have to answer the door etc etc etc

Comment: @GayotFow Ohhhh. In movies I've always seen it placed there before you arrived, not delivered to the door. I suppose that is a valid concern.

Answer (score 2):

Delivery would depend partially on what package was ordered. Things like fruit plates, red wines could be placed in your cabin before you embark.  Things like champagne or white wines which are served chilled on ice would likely be brought after you are in your cabin.  An experienced cabin steward would ask you when you would like it delivered.

This can vary from ship to ship within a cruise line, as the purser or guest services manager will formulate their own procedures for their ship (hence why central res can't specifically tell you).

If you or a friend are ordering the pakage, you can usually ask that they deliver it on a certain day or time.